# Azure DevOps Project pipeline not able to access NuGet package from Artifact Feed in different Collection

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

Our organization has two separate collections

```
Application Development
    Foobar Inc (Project)
        Repo / Build pipeline (Pipeline)

External Applications (Collection)
   External Applications (Project)
       Artifacts
           XYZ_SharedPackages (Nuget feed)
```

When I run the restore command for a project in Appliction Development for the Foobar Inc project I get

```
    "C:\agent\_work\76\s\Foobar_Inc\Foobar_IncUI\Foobar_IncUI.csproj" (Restore target) (1) ->
       (Restore target) -> 
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.200\NuGet.targets(130,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source 
http://svp042iis/tfs/Application%20Development/_packaging/XYZ_SharedPackages/nuget/v3/index.json. 
[C:\agent\_work\76\s\Foobar_Inc\Foobar_IncUI\Foobar_IncUI.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.200\NuGet.targets(130,5): error : Response status code does not indicate 
success: 404 (Not Found - The feed with ID 'XYZ_SharedPackages' doesn't exist. (DevOps Activity ID: 5C76EC84-96B7-4125-BA30-296CF33B1754)). 
[C:\agent\_work\76\s\Foobar_Inc\Foobar_IncUI\Foobar_IncUI.csproj]
```

The 404 error is coming from the source not existing, however I selected that feed by going into the restore command and selecting that option under feeds to use. My question is, does anyone know if it's possible to share across collections in dev ops.

Comment: Have you tried to add a feed in a different collection?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/how-to/set-up-upstream-sources?view=azure-devops-2022#add-a-feed-in-a-different-organization-as-an-upstream-source

Answer (score 0):

If your two organziations are `NOT` in same AAD, you can follow below methods:

Method1:

You can use a NuGet authenticate task and a powershell task to run the nuget install command in the pipeline with the Feed URL of the target feed.

1. Create a `Nuget Service connection` to the target organization.

Target feed URL:`https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{orgname}/_packaging/{feedname}/nuget/v3/index.json`, The password is PAT.

[image]

2.Add `NuGet authenticate` task before your restore.
[image]

3. Use the `powershell` task in line script.The in line script :
   `nuget install {package name} -version {package version} -Source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{orgname}/_packaging/{feedname}/nuget/v3/index.json.`

[image]

It will restore the package successfully.
[image]

Method 2:

Directly use a `powershell` task with inline script:
`nuget install {package name} -version {package version} -Source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{orgname}/_packaging/{feedname}/nuget/v3/index.json.`

The two Environment Variables needs to be set:

• NUGET_CREDENTIALPROVIDER_SESSIONTOKENCACHE_ENABLED=true

• VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS= {"endpointCredentials": [{"endpoint":"https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{orgname}/_packaging/{feedname}/nuget/v3/index.json", "username":"optional", "password":"$(PAT)"}]}

[image]

If your two organizations are in same AAD, you can follow below steps：

1. Please check the permissions in Feed Settings -> Views. Then change the access permissions for Local view in more options-> edit, choose “All feeds and people in organizations associated with my Azure Active.
   [image: 2. List item]
2. Setup upstream resource :
   [image]
3. On the upstream feed, add `project collection build service` account as contributor or collab or owner role.